# Dynamic form radio buttons mess up foreach loop mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic form that has all dynamic arrays being set to my php mysql insert script. The records only get inserted correctly if I have all of my radio buttons checked. If I leave any unchecked random records get inserted.
It's an attendance table and the inputs below repeat for each person. I'm checking their option with the radio button.

I've looked at the js hack of assigning a hidden input and disabling it if one of my radio buttons get checked but I find that a little weird.

My radio buttons have a value of 1 attend or 2 dive and I'm checking for that value in my script. I have a +1 set on the [$key+1] but that only works if all radios are checked. I appreciate any help pointing me in the correct direction as to setting my loop to only grab the data in the array when the radio is checked.

Thanks for looking

The two offending radio buttons are setup like this with the rest off the variables being set from hidden fields and are all filled with actual values. Everything gets insert if I don't use radio buttons in the form or if they're  all checked.

```
<input  type="radio" name="dive_attend_points['.$row1['_rowid_'].'][dive_attend]" value="'.$dive_points.'">
<input  type="radio" name="dive_attend_points['.$row1['_rowid_'].'][dive_attend]" value="'.$attend_points.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="_rowid_[]" value="' .$row1['_rowid_']. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="location_date[]" value="' .$location_date. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="location_name[]" value="' .$location_name. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="first_name[]" value="' .$row1['first_name']. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="last_name[]" value="' .$row1['last_name']. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="cert_agency[]" value="' .$row1['cert_agency']. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="high_cert[]" value="' .$row1['high_cert']. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="' .$row1['email']. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="phone_number[]" value="' .$row1['phone_number']. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="photo_release[]" value="' .$row1['photo_release']. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="diver_pic[]" value="' .$row1['diver_pic']. '">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted_email[]" value="' . $submitted_email . '">    
        <input type="hidden" name="food_option[]" value="' .$row2['food_option']. '">
```

My php loop is setup like this.

```
foreach ($_POST['location_date'] as $key => $value) {

    $_rowid_ = $_POST['_rowid_'][$key];
    $location_date = $_POST['location_date'][$key];
    $location_name = $_POST['location_name'][$key];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'][$key];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'][$key];
    $cert_agency = $_POST['cert_agency'][$key];
    $high_cert = $_POST['high_cert'][$key];
    $email = $_POST['email'][$key];
    $phone_number= $_POST['phone_number'][$key];
    $photo_release = $_POST['photo_release'][$key];
    $diver_pic = $_POST['diver_pic'][$key];
    $submitted_email = $_POST['submitted_email'][$key];
    $food_option = $_POST['food_option'][$key];

    foreach ($_POST['dive_attend_points'][$key+1] as $row) {
        $dive_attend = $row['dive_attend'];

        if (!empty($dive_attend)) {
            if($dive_attend == 1) {
                $dive_points = 0;
                $attend_points = 1;
            } elseif($dive_attend == 2) {
                $dive_points = 2;
                $attend_points = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if($dive_attend == 1 || $dive_attend == 2){
        //mysql insert here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you could make this easier to answer by providing the actual HTML output, not the PHP used to make it, and also provide a few more lines of the HTML. For example, how does 'location_date' figure into this?

Comment: I added the rest of the inputs that I'm setting variables with for the loop. Their all hidden and out of users control. The only field I'm letting them set is the radio button. This is a dynamic html table listing users so these repeat for every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I've never seen or heard of this until I saw it in a post while doing research. To keep your arrays aligned with the same indexes is you assign an index dynamically or manually. In my case I used the same `'.$row1['_rowid_'].'` I was using to give my radio button group a unique name so they grouped properly. I placed it inside the empty [] for each input. This technique allowed me to not use those clunky js hacks.

**HTML**

```
    <input  type="radio" name="dive_attend_points['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="'.$dive_points.'">
    <input  type="radio" name="dive_attend_points['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="'.$attend_points.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="_rowid_['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$row1['_rowid_']. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="location_date['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$location_date. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="location_name['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$location_name. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$row1['first_name']. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$row1['last_name']. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="cert_agency['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$row1['cert_agency']. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="high_cert['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$row1['high_cert']. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="email['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$row1['email']. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="phone_number['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$row1['phone_number']. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="photo_release['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$row1['photo_release']. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="diver_pic['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' .$row1['diver_pic']. '">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted_email['.$row1['_rowid_'].']" value="' . $submitted_email . '">    
    <input type="hidden" name="food_option['.$row1['_rowid_'].']"  value="' .$row2['food_option']. '">
```

**The adjusted php**

```
foreach ($_POST['location_date'] as $key => $value) {

$_rowid_ = $_POST['_rowid_'][$key];
$location_date = $_POST['location_date'][$key];
$location_name = $_POST['location_name'][$key];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'][$key];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'][$key];
$cert_agency = $_POST['cert_agency'][$key];
$high_cert = $_POST['high_cert'][$key];
$email = $_POST['email'][$key];
$phone_number= $_POST['phone_number'][$key];
$photo_release = $_POST['photo_release'][$key];
$diver_pic = $_POST['diver_pic'][$key];
$submitted_email = $_POST['submitted_email'][$key];
$food_option = $_POST['food_option'][$key];

$dive_attend = $_POST['dive_attend_points'][$key]



        if($dive_attend == 1) {
            $dive_points = 0;
            $attend_points = 1;
           } elseif($dive_attend == 2) {
            $dive_points = 2;
            $attend_points = 0;
           }




    //mysql insert here.

} //end of for each
```